# Life without Nitrogen

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology

On Earth life has six fundamental building blocks for life with them being Hydrogen, Carbon, Nitrogen, Oxygen, Phosphorus, and Sulfur. [(1)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AP_Biology/The_Chemical_Building_Blocks_of_Life) Those elements of help make up more complex life through amino acids, proteins, nucleic acids / DNA, along with a lot of other things. [(2)](https://www.britannica.com/science/amino-acid) [(3)](https://www.livescience.com/37247-dna.html)

Though when it comes to the possibility of extraterrestrial life and xenobiology some individuals like to explore the idea that not all life has to use the exact same forms of life found on Earth. Most popular of which seems to be finding alternatives for Carbon and solvents. [(4)](http://speculativeevolution.wikia.com/wiki/Alternative_biochemistry) [(5)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_types_of_biochemistry) [(6)](http://www.xenology.info/Xeno/8.2.htm)

Now when I looked through this all it seemed like the possible forms of alternate life had little bounds for having something in common. Carbon based could be replaced with Silicon or Boron-Nitrogen, Phosphorus replaced  by Arsenic, water replaced with ammonia, and so on with varying degrees of possibility. The only thing that cannot be replaced it seems is the need for Nitrogen.

At first I foolishly thought that like Carbon being replaced with Silicon or Phosphorus being replaced with Arsenic one could just use the same idea with Nitrogen. The problem is below Nitrogen is Phosphorus, already being used for the building blocks of life. I tried to think of a way that Phosphorus could just replace Nitrogen completely somehow and do the almost same job, though learning from the objections to Silicon based life just because elements share the same family does not mean they can replace each other.

So that left me rather stuck, as we understand how life works right now, is all life in the universe bound to have to use Nitrogen in some way or another? Or have I completely messed up, missed something, and dealing with a case of Nitrogen chauvinism?

Comment: From chemical standpoint, it's not too difficult to imagine a set of organic molecules that don't include nitrogen. However, from what we know about planets, it's difficult to imagine a planet where all other elements are present, but nitrogen is very rare.

Comment: Consider that your "nitrogen chauvinism" may simply be part of a 'bell curve' representation that describes both prevalence of an element and its ability to react with other elements.  While helium is very common, its is essentially inert. Phosphorus on the other hand is far less common, but highly reactive, and at a wide variety of temperatures and conditions.  I suggest that Nitrogen is a kind of 'crossroads' of the elements, light enough to be common, reactive enough to be in thousands (or more) molecules.

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, I suppose my question should have been more along the lines of what could possibly replace Nitrogen. I understand the problem that Nitrogen is just the best. Though would you know what that set of organic molecules would use in place of Nitrogen if environmental factors were not limiting?

Comment: I don't think you are messing up as this is not a simple subject but I think a clearer understanding of the distinction of elements and molecular componds would help. It is hard to get away from nitrogen because it probably one of the top 10 most common elements but is possible to have amino acid analog without an amino (N-containing) group. ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements

Comment: "is all life in the universe bound to have to use Nitrogen in some way or another?" This is probably true for life as we know it. But there are much more exotic processes in the universe that could be alive and we'd never know because we don't have any frame of reference for them.

Comment: I work in planetary science, and regularly discuss origin of life with astrophysicists. I'm buddies with some of the arsenic-instead-of-phosphorous folks that thought they found a new kind of DNA in Lake Mono. (They REALLY should have done some gradient separation before their press conference.) 1/2

Comment: 2/2 Your post is just too clumsy. Where did you look? What are the links? Some of the genera I've isolated fix nitrogen in new ways, some are oxygenic. There are biochemical pathways galore out there. BUT you have a hand wavy Q with no links. I'm not inclined to give it any thought. But it is fundamental, so I have read it a few times. If you give more DETAIL (not words) it would be easier to answer.

Comment: @DPT Ah, well sorry for not making it clear. The last three links are just the most popular searches for alternative biochemistry results that give the most information. The first three are just basic information on what is amino acids and DNA. Most of what I looked for and at brings up alternatives for Carbon and solvents like water. Trying to search for life without Nitrogen or things that do not use Nitrogen do not bring up a lot for me. Probably because I am using the wrong words to look for the question. And it is not really pissy at all I understand.

Comment: You are right that the most obvious choice is phosphorous, because of the valance state.

Comment: We (biomolecules) use O and S, for different reasons, but same valance. They don't exchange. S is very good at linking molecules (disulfides.) If you want to exchange N for another, you need to use P, but P will be less abundant (at least astro-chemically) but you can work around that. I would suggest thinking along the lines of stable isotopes. You might come up with something interesting.

Comment: @DPT Thank you for letting me know that, it pretty much answers my concern for the most part, gives me a new direction to start looking. Probably be the closest thing to an answer I will get. So if no one else writes an answer, I would be happy to accept that little bit of information there as an answer.

Comment: Well, meh, it wasn't much help. I didn't see your links before - not sure why. Maybe my browser.  Anyway, at least you know you asked.

Comment: Advice: if you don't know the basics of one field of science (chemistry and biochemistry), don't write fancy fiction about it. Say it just works and skip the details or write another story or spend 8 years being educated in that field first. Don't take this the wrong way, but you would write a story about the Netherlands if you couldn't find it on a map either

Comment: where do you think amino acid come from? no nitrogen no amino acid no protein no plant and animal as we know it.

Comment: There were many experiments and scientific papers about alternative biologies. No conclusions, at least no consensus. I think you seen it already. It's not really possible to answer here what science couldn't answer over years.

Comment: We do not even have a solid definition of what **life** is in a universal context, meaning your questions is unanswerable. Essentially you are asking *"Hey, can I have **DNA-based life as we know it already**, just swapping out the elements?"*. Well that is kind of narrow-minded, don't you think? What is it says that "life" of any sort **must** be based on DNA or DNA-like structures?!

Comment: @user6760 Why can't something replace nitrogen in amino acids?

Comment: @MichaelK Yeah I figured it was narrow-minded, but looking at the hypothetical alternatives of switching out one thing for another I just wondered why not Nitrogen too?

Comment: An alternative is a different path entirely, the Singularity. PC brains in self-replicating machines. Created by us. ix-nay N, but has Si.

Answer (score 2):

First, There are no known organisms whose DNA are composed with silicon or boron-Nitrogen or arsenic. **These are theoretical** possibilities based on the **assumption** that these elements/compounds can be substituted for their equivalent in the **DNA Model**. We don't know for sure that these substitutions can even work, because as you mentioned, just because two elements share the same family and ionic charge does not mean that resulting compounds will share the same properties.

Currently, Arsenic can end up in our DNA, when this happens it actually causes damage. This is how arsenic kills.

**What the previous approaches all have in common is they all try to modify the current DNA Model.**

All DNA is, is a means to store information that governs the construction and operation of a cell.

**So to start answering your question:**

Create an alternative DNA model that has 4 non-nitrogen compounds (in place of the amino acids), that can be used to organically synthesize proteins(or compounds similar to).

Obviously, this is a much greater effort than picking similar ions to swap out in the current DNA Model but its more realistic as you avoid the unproven property deficit.

**Further rationality:**

All life as we know it uses DNA, but all life as we know it exists on Earth. If we found extraterrestrial life on an extra-solar planet that used DNA that would lend credibility to [Panspermia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panspermia). Conversely, if we didn't that would mean life as we know it potentially did evolve independently on Earth. This is why it is foolish to assume that extra-terrestrial life will conform to the same genetic model we do.

Comment: Its sort of a cop out answer, however you are trying to change a variable of a complex and elegant equation, I'm just saying, change the equation.

Comment: Well I would rather have a nice cop out answer than no answer at all. Least it lets me know that there was no easy to find paper or something on the internet about theoretically replacing Nitrogen like Carbon. Though now I guess I will have to start stop thinking narrowly.

Answer (score 1):

The honest answer is we don’t know because we have only one example biosphere to go on, that being Earth's. But we can make some educated guesses.

Firstly a few points should be noted. Nitrogen is one of the lighter elements, its more easily formed in stars than the heavier elements and it’s believed to be a relatively common element. So it’s unlikely that a world would exist without any.

Although it’s true that chemicals within the same column of the periodic table show many similarities, as you have already pointed out one element is not replaceable by another as increasing atomic weight (among other things) has a very profound effect on properties. Silicon does form many complex compounds showing properties in some ways similar to carbon, but its abilities are a pale shadow of the enormous multitude of compounds possible with carbon.

Also compare the relatively benign ammonia with its nightmarish brother borane (or more strictly diborane as borane molecules unlike ammonia have a tendency to dimerise to form B2H6) which is spontaneously flammable on contact with air and contains unusual B-H-B triple atom bonds.

So to answer your question I would suggest yes other life in the universe probably does use Nitrogen because it is so abundant. However if nitrogen was not present for any reason I would think that there is sufficient reactivity and complexity to be had with the other elements to create an alternative biosphere without it. In this case the many different nitrogen compounds in nature would be replaced by an array of different chemicals, not necessarily by those of a single element.

Comment: An array of different chemicals, huh. Thank you for that idea, gives me some more things to look up now.